# System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult] instead of view while login and registration users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Below code is getting the error `` System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult] `` instead of view while logging in and registering users in MVC:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

when trying to login getting error `System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult]` instead of view.
Same error while registering users.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");    
        }

        AddErrors(result);
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: When you step through the `Login` code in the debugger, what is the value of `result`?

Comment: What do you mean *getting error `System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult]`*? What is the actual error message?

Comment: @Rahul: You tagged your question ASP.NET MVC 5; are you sure that's the version you're using?

Comment: @Rahul: I am having the same problem, did you find a solution?